# Changing color with resource in click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How would I be able to change the color of the shape on the click event to the color of my resource?

```
public void BtnBlue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleSolid.

    }

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBlue" Color="Blue" />
```

Comment: Where did you define the static resource?

Comment: In the programs resource dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
RectangleSolid.Fill = (Brush)myWindow.TryFindResource("SolidBlue");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work provided that the `ResourceDictionary` in which `SolidBlue` is defined is in scope:

```
RectangleSolid.Fill = (Brush)TryFindResource("SolidBlue");
```

You could for example define the resource in your `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBlue" Color="Red" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```